# lync extension development

Tags: lync-2010, lync

Could anyone please send me some urls or code samples for develop extension for lync 2010.

I mean development some tools which can integrated into lync 2010 as extension.
add a menu or button to lync 2010, when click the menu or button, the customerized tool will popup.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got 4 options:

1 - Add a [custom menu item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg436762.aspx) to either the main Lync window or a conversation window.

2 - Create a [Conversation Window Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg436808.aspx) to host your custom functionality. This is a Silverlight or HTML application that can be hosted inside a conversation window. Note, this can only be applied to a conversation window, and not to the main Lync window.

3 - Create a Silverlight or WPF application that contains your custom functionality, and then [automate Lync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg437053.aspx) from that application

4 - Probably a bit extreme depending on what you're trying to achieve, but you could run Lync in [UI suppression mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg436850.aspx), and then create your custom functionality in an application that also uses Lync for communication related tasks - but in this case, you'll have to provide all the communication UI (e.g. conversation windows) yourself.

The Lync SDK can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d98f0bf7-c82c-47f5-9f73-be3edbf30438) - This contains sample code and walkthroughs, and should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot. and is there any way to add some ui elements into lync client main window?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the option to add custom tabs into the main Contact window has been removed in Lync.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a solution at

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/29576efc-0d12-4ad8-8ace-6a9a63275a57

Using this package, you can add custom tab functionality to lync 2010 client.